# Actionbar Logo size?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, size, graphical-logo

In the Google I/O 2012 Android App an actionbar logo is used instead of the normal app icon. In the open source project I could find the image which is 340x72 and present only in this dimension. I searched if there is some specified size for using a logo in the actionbar, but I did not find anything. Do you know something about this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I looked into the resources of the YouTube app, since that seems to be the only official Google app (besides I/O) that uses an action bar logo at the moment.

It contains three drawables for the logo:

- drawable-**mdpi**/ic_logo_wide.png (75 x **32** px)
- drawable-**hdpi**/ic_logo_wide.png (112 x **48** px)
- drawable-**xhdpi**/ic_logo_wide.png (149 x **64** px)

According to [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar) from the Android design guidelines, those images' heights match the specification for the action bar icons, which is **32 x 32 dp**.

- 32 dp = **32** px (MDPI)
- 32 dp * 1.5 = **48** px (HDPI)
- 32 dp * 2 = **64** px (XHDPI)

You'll notice that the **72** px (XHDPI) from the I/O app don't show up. I guess, they just wanted to increase the logo's height a bit.

If a drawable is only provided in XHDPI, Android scales it down, which is a little less performant than providing the images in the proper sizes. I guess, this was just accepted by the developers of the I/O app.

Comment: But they should point this in the documentation, you don't believe?

Comment: Would not be a miss. On the other hand, it is clear that any height value between **32 dp** (action bar icon) and **48 dp** (launcher icon) will fit well.

Comment: But there is not clear what happens with the width. There are actionbar items that appear only in case of enough space, if the logo is to width, could there be a problem with this?

Comment: I don't know. I suppose it pushes everything away except the overflow button. That would be a pretty wide logo, though.

Comment: Note to self :)

32 dp * 3 = 96 px (XXHDPI)

Comment: And 32 dp * 4 = 128 px (XXXHDPI)

Comment: Why does my Logo appear in the middle of my acitonbar. using AppCompat for backwards compatibility and having the worst time getting my actionbar looking nice. AppCompat is the worst, I just want it left aligned. :(

Comment: @tantonj Try setting showtitle to enabled and displaying "" as title.

Comment: Second note to self :) 186 x 96 (xxhdpi) , 223 x 128 (xxxhdpi)