# Android ActionBar with text and image in title

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

I need to have something like this in My application ActionBar

logo image + Application name  + trademark

I was reading about adding a custom logo to use it in ActionBar and to hide the title, but the problem is (if I try to create a .png file that will contain logo+title+trademark) with the width (there are dimensions specified for this logo).

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action bar style, set the displayOptions to:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
```

Now it will only display the logo, and not the app icon or title. The logo can be as wide as you want I think.

Set the logo on the Application tag of your manifest

```
android:logo="@drawable/my_logo"
```

Comment: Ok, I will try. I was reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248207/actionbar-logo-size, so I thought that width is fixed as well. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Setting logo is working, but as I needed to add trademark I just added it in string at the end.

Comment: Don't forget to use `useLogo|showHome` for AppCompat Action Bars