# Scaling issue:How to make android actionBar icon rectangular?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, image-resizing, image-scaling, android-icons

I am developing simple android application in which I want to Customise my `actionBar` icon which is generally named ic_launcher.png in `drawable` directory.The issue I am facing is in **scaling and resizing** of icon image.

> Can I add rectangular image as Icon(`ic_launcher.png`) ?

because everytime I upload an **rectangular icon** the eclipse generates a square image,hence diminishing image size.

> This is what I am looking for:

[image]

> And this is what I have currently:

[image]

Note:Images aren't from actula project and are taken just for referencial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell the Actionbar to use a logo instead of an icon.

See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setLogo(int)

and this:

[Actionbar Logo size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248207/actionbar-logo-size)